# Store credentials in secure library in java

Tags: java

I need to write automated test scripts for webapp and tests require user credentials for login recieved from csv file. The problem is that it's my personal credentials and they are shared for some other services but all project is under svn and I need some way to hide my credentials.
I there some way to store credentials in some "closed" method or library and get credentials with methods like getUserName() and getPassword().

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps store them as hashed, and then unhash them when you need them (using some private little script/application for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can save them to properties file and encrypt it.. Now, when your web application up, it will decrypt file and read all credentials store in memory using java.util.Properties and than you can use them whenever you want.